# How to launch My Website in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web

I have bought new Domine name that is:unitedspectrumsolutions.asia

But Now I want to know how to upload in my wordpress project and link to the website

so could you please tell me the detail step by step to launch my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just follow the steps:**

1.**login to FTP**(login detail provided by service provider)

2.**upload database through cpanel**(adjust all the url like http://www.unitedspectrumsolutions.asia in database)Also,db connection in wp-config.php-username,password should be used that you made in cpanel

3.**upload your whole project file** through ftp.
For e.g, if unitedspectrumsolutions is folder in your local machine then,upload all the files that are inside this folder inside www folder of your ftp.replace all existing files while you upload your project file.

Thats done. Enjoy.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. First upload all files to the new domain root(www) using  FTP manager
2. Dump your database into sql file from your old Cpanel
3. Upload your SQL to new website using Cpanel
4. Now update wp-config file of your wordpress as new database name, password etc
5. Follow this link. [Wordpress Migration Script](http://www.sagardevkota.com.np/blog/easy-wordpress-migration-script/)