# Showing default theme when uploading WordPress website on server

Tags: php, wordpress

When I upload my existing WordPress website on server. Its not showing exact as it is on local machine. I have already changed the link http://localhost to http://mywebsite link in .SQL file even than it not showing exactly as it is on local machine local...

At local machine its looking like this...

[image]

And when I uploading its all package on server then its showing default theme like this..

[image]

What should I to do to get as it is as on local machine look...

I have tried it with duplicator plugin to migrate it on server and also tried it manually like I first export the database from local server and then opened it in notepad. After that I find localhost link in whole file and replace it with my website link like: `www.mywebsite.com/pmx2` and then I upload it on my main server...
When I am making changes in `enigma_option` table data with the updating link then its showing the default theme else its working fine as I want except the images of slider and our team section images...

Here is my `enigma_option` table data:

```
_ a:74:{s:17:"upload_image_logo";s:61:"http://jeeaayanu.com/pmx2/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/logo.jpg";s:6:"height";s:3:"100";s:5:"width";s:3:"200";s:10:"_frontpage";s:1:"1";s:10:"text_title";s:0:"";s:20:"upload_image_favicon";s:0:"";s:10:"custom_css";s:21:"background-color:gray";s:13:"slide_image_1";s:109:"http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/studying-699485_1280_pixabay_crop640_resize1080-1080x420.png";s:13:"slide_title_1";s:11:"Slide Title";s:12:"slide_desc_1";s:47:"pmp experto pmp experto pmp experto pmp experto";s:16:"slide_btn_text_1";s:9:"Read More";s:16:"slide_btn_link_1";s:10:"google.com";s:13:"slide_image_2";s:97:"http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/book-408302_1280_pixabay_resize1080-1080x420.jpg";s:13:"slide_title_2";s:22:"variations of passages";s:12:"slide_desc_2";s:65:"Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text";s:16:"slide_btn_text_2";s:9:"Read More";s:16:"slide_btn_link_2";s:1:"#";s:13:"slide_image_3";s:72:"http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/slide4_1080-856x333.jpg";s:13:"slide_title_3";s:19:"Contrary to popular";s:12:"slide_desc_3";s:63:"Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum, rutrum turpi";s:16:"slide_btn_text_3";s:9:"Read More";s:16:"slide_btn_link_3";s:1:"#";s:8:"fc_title";s:75:"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ";s:10:"fc_btn_txt";s:13:"More Features";s:11:"fc_btn_link";s:1:"#";s:30:"header_social_media_in_enabled";s:1:"1";s:34:"footer_section_social_media_enbled";s:1:"1";s:12:"twitter_link";s:1:"#";s:7:"fb_link";s:42:"https://www.facebook.com/bajrang.mittal.58";s:13:"linkedin_link";s:1:"#";s:12:"youtube_link";s:1:"#";s:9:"instagram";s:1:"#";s:5:"gplus";s:1:"#";s:8:"email_id";s:18:"example@mymail.com";s:8:"phone_no";s:10:"0159753586";s:21:"footer_customizations";s:25:" &#169; 2015 Enigma Theme";s:17:"developed_by_text";s:18:"Theme Developed By";s:26:"developed_by_weblizar_text";s:15:"Weblizar Themes";s:17:"developed_by_link";s:20:"http://weblizar.com/";s:20:"home_service_heading";s:0:"";s:15:"service_1_title";s:15:"UPCOMING EVENTS";s:15:"service_1_icons";s:12:"fa fa-google";s:14:"service_1_text";s:16:"Delhi 11-10-2014";s:14:"service_1_link";s:1:"#";s:15:"service_2_title";s:12:"Testimonials";s:15:"service_2_icons";s:14:"fa fa-database";s:14:"service_2_text";s:155:"I have recently got my PMP cleared......

 I would like to thank Praveen Sir for providing superb......

 I was fortunate to be coached by Praveen.......";s:14:"service_2_link";s:1:"#";s:15:"service_3_title";s:14:"Free Resources";s:15:"service_3_icons";s:15:"fa fa-wordpress";s:14:"service_3_text";s:41:"PMBOK ACRONYMS

 PMP TIPS

 PMP FORMULA";s:14:"service_3_link";s:1:"#";s:14:"portfolio_home";s:1:"1";s:12:"port_heading";s:15:"OUR INSTRUCTORS";s:10:"port_1_img";s:60:"http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/imagesc.jpg";s:12:"port_1_title";s:11:"Ashwini Rao";s:11:"port_1_link";s:37:"http://localhost/port/index.php/team/";s:10:"port_2_img";s:61:"http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Pervesh3.jpg";s:12:"port_2_title";s:15:"Parvesh Dhingra";s:11:"port_2_link";s:48:"http://localhost/port/index.php/parvesh-dhingra/";s:10:"port_3_img";s:60:"http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Sandeep.jpg";s:12:"port_3_title";s:15:"Sandeep Shouche";s:11:"port_3_link";s:48:"http://localhost/port/index.php/sandeep-shouche/";s:10:"port_4_img";s:59:"http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/indexa.jpg";s:12:"port_4_title";s:13:"Praveen Malik";s:11:"port_4_link";s:46:"http://localhost/port/index.php/praveen-malik/";s:9:"show_blog";s:1:"1";s:10:"blog_title";s:11:"Latest Blog";s:33:"weblizar_settings_save_home-image";s:1:"1";s:11:"style_sheet";s:14:"light-blue.css";s:30:"weblizar_settings_save_general";s:1:"1";s:41:"weblizar_settings_save_portfolio-settings";s:1:"1";s:35:"weblizar_settings_save_home-service";s:1:"1";s:29:"weblizar_settings_save_social";s:1:"1";}
```

Here I am to change the link to http://localhost/port/ to http://jeeaayanu.com/pmx2/.
But when I am changing it its showing default theme. So please tell me how do I change it.

Comment: You are not telling us how are you migrating the website to online server. Also what is the problem, images? or other things also?

Comment: I edited my question now..so please have look on question again..

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but I can tell you that you can't use a text editor to "find and replace the URL". Because database values are serialized you will corrupt the data and it will probably fallback to the themes default values (based on your screenshots). I'd use migrate db pro, or backup buddy, here is a link:
https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/videos/

Comment: when I am follow this process and then import it on server. Its showing nothing after that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually theme settings are stored in an encoded way in the database. For exemple a background image setting will kind of look like that :

```
background:14:path\/image.jpg
```

So options are stored in this format:

```
type:length:value
```

If you change the path of your background image, then it will change the length of the value - so the length attribute will no more be valid. It will make the settings import fail (all the encoded string will be considered as invalid), and theme will use default options.

Often themes have an import / export functionality. You should check on that, if there is no such functionality, then you'll have to set up again all your theme options, or look for the theme options encoded string in `wp_options` and use the following script to fix the lengths:

```
$corrupted_serialized_data = '... your theme option strings here from option_value ...';
$fixed_serialized_data =  preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $corrupted_serialized_data );
print $fixed_serialized_data;
```

And update the option with this new string.

Comment: How to check for a themes have an import / export functionality?

Comment: I don't see any reference about an import / export functionality in your [https://weblizar.com/documentation/themes/enigma-premium-documentation/](theme documentation), so I don't think sadly that there is such option. Could you log in your phpMyAdmin, execute that following query : `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE "%enigma%`" and share the results?

Comment: I got two records with this:- option id:-138, option_name:theme_mods_enigma, option_value:a:2:{i:0;b:0;s:18:"nav_menu_locations";a:1:{s:7:"primary";i:2;}}, autoload:Yes

Comment: I see only one record. Perhaps edit your question and add the full `option_value` inside it so we can check both of the values. There must be an url somewhere in that encoded string.

Comment: option id::=147, option_name::=enigma_options, option_value::=

Comment: The `option_value` for the option 147 is empty?

Comment: unable to comment second column option_value due to character limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84059/discussion-between-anil-kr-vijay-and-vard).

Comment: I used the option value as you corrected but still getting same problem

Comment: From what I see there is still some wrong URLs, like on the slider: `http://localhost/port/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/slide2_1080-856x333.jpg`. I suggest you to export your database from the live server, check again all your url (search for `localhost` only), fix them, [run this script](https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization) on your database export to fix all serialized data, then import the file.

Comment: I search again in exported file but there is no 'localhost'

Comment: It must be in a template then. I suggest you to search in your whole project files any reference of `localhost`. Did you tried the script to fix your sql export too?

Comment: when I am changing the engina_option table data, then its showing default theme else its working fine. so please tell how do I fix that.

Comment: Did you processed the script as I told you on the option string? Btw you have an error at the beginning of your string: `_ a:74:` should be `a:74:`. Be carefull with this string, if there is any typo in it `unserialize` will fail then the theme will use default settings.

Comment: but Now I changes it from admin panel on server.there is have custom slider images and custom logo option. so I change the all localhost link from there. so now Its working as I want.....

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to zip your theme you created on your local machine.

Then, export the database. I recommend using phpmyadmin, but any export of the DB will do (.sql file).

Then you set up your wordpress online. Database and all. Install your theme and **don't go to frontend**.

Now use this [nifty script for replacing old links in DB with new one](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB). And follow the steps provided on the site (it's really straightforward really, just set the old and new info from the DB and hit dry run).

***Backup everything***

This will search old links from your localhost, and replace them with the ones on the live server.

When you're sure everything is ok, just click live run and let it replace the links. After this you should have a working, same wp on your server as on your local machine.

Works for me every time.

Comment: I followed these step already. I changed the all local links to server links and then import it to server But still it showing same problem..

Comment: I also tried it to with Duplicator plugin that is use to move your local WordPress website to server.But I am not getting the solution for this with this also..

Comment: I never trust plugins. This is probably the safest method. The only thing that is different from your local is the logo, and the slider, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is the problem in your theme.

So far i understand your problem, you did not upload total files in live site,

Did you upload uploads folder which lies in wp-content folder?

It is good to upload whole wp-content instead of your theme only.

After you update your database, the content too should be there so that you can display what you want.

Also don't forget to switch the theme from backend.

[Click Here to know how to live your site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248147/how-to-launch-my-website-in-wordpress/)

Cheers :) !!!