# Files uploaded one domain to another domain but menu not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have configured a site using WP on my Development Server and now I have moved it to another server with new URL. I have changed URL in database as well. But, my menus are pointing to the OLD URL and I am getting a 404 error.

How can I change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use some wordpress plugins to migrate your website between servers.

Duplicator is one of them.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

You will have to do minimum effort if you use some tools.

Answer (score 0):

Make SQL dump, overwrite old domain, load dump.

Also checks configuration files & themes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forget some links in your database. Check the following fields:

In `wp_options`, options with the following `option_name`:

`siteurl`, `home`

In `wp_posts`:

Check all the `guid` values.

You need also to check that your `.htaccess` is using the correct `RewriteBase`.

If your menus are built from a special theme feature (not the default WP menu functionality), you may have some encoded string in `wp_options` that reflect the menu settings. If so [check on this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379912/showing-default-theme-when-uploading-wordpress-website-on-server/31559223#31559223).