# How can I change entire URL when transfer same WordPress database to another domain database?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site called: *www.myfirstwp.com*.

I want to transfer it's database to new domain which is www.mynewwp.com.

I did it by exporting the DB from www.myfirstwp.com and imported it to www.mynewwp.com

But in this new site ( www.mynewwp.com ) database have all old one database URL.

So, How can I change entire url of old one (www.myfirstwp.com) database in new one ( www.mynewwp.com ) database? Is there any way to do this?

Thank You.

**Update Question :**

I have an issue in WordPress. When I try to importing XML file with Attachments it's showing me following error message :

**Error Message :**

Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log. Apache Server at mysite.com Port 80

what should I do to solve this type of error message as I am a new user in WordPress.

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing default theme when uploading WordPress website on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379912/showing-default-theme-when-uploading-wordpress-website-on-server)

Comment: This is a duplicate question. I gave answer how to transfer wordpress on many questions For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31555721/629127

Comment: @dingo_d Thank You. I got it.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs) has everything you need.

Comment: Use this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
Install this plugin on both server and you will get option to export and import everything.

Comment: @dingo_d I have a update question. Can you please answer me ?

Comment: Why are you exporting xml? Just zip your theme, create a new wordpress locally. Export your sql from phpmyadmin, on your local installation, get wordpress going, import database (in phpmyadmin), install your theme, BEFORE even going to the page, and this is crucial: DO NOT OPEN YOUR LOCAL PAGE, run search and replace script. Then follow the instructions replacing your links with local ones, and once that's done you're set. A working copy should be on your local host.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: before you tinker with your database be sure to grab a backup first. You do *not* want to mess up a production database.

The simple way is to open the database on your new domain, open `{$prefix}_options` and change the `home` and `siteurl` rows to reflect the new domain.

This approach works and allows you to operate the site at minimum. The other problems include:

- Embedded media links which use the old domain
- Other post meta fields and option fields that may contain the old domain.

What I do when this happens is to use raw SQL inside phpMyAdmin (or similar) to search and replace. The following queries take care of post meta and options (95% of the time):

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com');
```

The following tables and columns usually have contained domain references in WP:

- `wp_options.option_value`
- `wp_postmeta.meta_value`
- `wp_posts.post_content`
- `wp_posts.guid`

But there might be more places where the domain has been inserted.