# WP Customizer theme settings disapearing after wp database restore/migrate

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to migrate an existing wordpress with a theme customized by the customizer.
I can get the wordpress up and running, but all of the theme customization has disappeared. I narrowed the problem to the customizer and the wp-options table in the database. There the option_value for the option theme_mods_{theme-name} is reset whenever I visit/reload the website. If I make changes via the customizer, they do appear, but if I change the value of the option_value within the database, the entire theme customization is removed.

I'm using a wordpress hosted on IIS, database is a MySql 5.x (don't know the exact version).

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've been facing this issue for a while and finally solved it. This anwser put me on the track : [Showing default theme when uploading WordPress website on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379912/showing-default-theme-when-uploading-wordpress-website-on-server)

When you migrated you probably changed the URL through your SQL file using find & replace. The thing is that the `theme_mods_{theme-name}` entry in the wp_options table is encoded as an object with this format : `type:length:value`
So, changing the value of one option, you might change his length too. If the length is not matching the value, WP will consider this object as invalid and will reset the option to the default `a:1:{s:18:"custom_css_post_id";i:-1;}`, breaking your menus and other customized options.

**Example:**

Working on localhost:

> a:4:{s:18:"custom_css_post_id";i:-1;s:18:"nav_menu_locations";a:5:{s:6:"menu-1";i:1120;s:6:"menu-2";i:1125;s:8:"top-menu";i:1120;s:8:"footer-1";i:1120;s:8:"footer-2";i:1125;}s:9:"my_option";s:29:"Lorem
>   ipsum";s:15:"posts_row_image";**s:32**:"http://localhost/lorem/dolor.png";}

Invalid on distant server:

> a:4:{s:18:"custom_css_post_id";i:-1;s:18:"nav_menu_locations";a:5:{s:6:"menu-1";i:1120;s:6:"menu-2";i:1125;s:8:"top-menu";i:1120;s:8:"footer-1";i:1120;s:8:"footer-2";i:1125;}s:9:"my_option";s:29:"Lorem
>   ipsum";s:15:"posts_row_image";**s:32**:"http://mydistantwebsite.com/lorem/dolor.png";}

Corrected length, working on distant server:

> a:4:{s:18:"custom_css_post_id";i:-1;s:18:"nav_menu_locations";a:5:{s:6:"menu-1";i:1120;s:6:"menu-2";i:1125;s:8:"top-menu";i:1120;s:8:"footer-1";i:1120;s:8:"footer-2";i:1125;}s:9:"my_option";s:29:"Lorem
>   ipsum";s:15:"posts_row_image";**s:43**:"http://mydistantwebsite.com/lorem/dolor.png";}

Comment: Some (not all) of my customizations was lost after switching to another theme, then back again. (I belive). My fix was to use a customizer export plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Manu's answer is the right one. I may add a small advice : updating serialized data via a sql request is a brain-burner. The only reasonable way to do it is to use wp-cli search-replace tool.

> Search/replace intelligently handles PHP serialized data, and does not change primary key values.
> https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/